# How do I use a message box in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I use a message box in C# without a script?

Comment: What do you mean by "with out script"? Is this WPF or Windows Forms? Have you looked at some of the documentation? This is currently very vague and difficult to answer.

Answer (score 9):

You haven't really specified your target application type, so:

- For a Console application:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine("hello world");
  ```
- For a WinForms/desktop application:

  ```
  MessageBox.Show("hello world");
  ```
- For a web application:

  ```
  alert('hello world');
  ```

  or you could also implement [custom dialogs](http://www.bitrepository.com/stylish-javascript-dialog-boxes.html) with javascript and jquery.

Answer (score 2):

```
MessageBox.Show()
```

have you tried [googling](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=show%20messagebox%20c#)?